# dir-paginate in table with nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using dir-paginate in a table which is a populated from nested ng-repeat data.
Tables are correctly populated but sorting and pagination when done in one table is resulting all remaining tables also. I used track by $index also, but not working.

```
   <div ng-repeat= "pData in parentData">
    {{PData.item}}

   <table>
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <tbody> 

   <tr dir-paginate="item in pData.appraisals|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:GenericSearch|itemsPerPage 
:10" pagination-id="policyHolderAppraisals"

 <td>{{item.b}}</td>
 <td>{{item.a}}</td>

 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done by using the  pagination-id to uniquely identify and group each pagination control for sorting, filtering etc.

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="customer in customers | itemsPerPage: 10" pagination-id="cust">{{ customer.name }}</li>
</ul>

<dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="cust"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="branch in branches | itemsPerPage: 10" pagination-id="branch">{{ customer.name }}</li>
</ul>

<dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="branch"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

More information can be found here
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#multiple-pagination-instances-on-one-page

Comment: I will not have any control over pagination-id, since this is a nested ng-repeat as u can see in parent div, entire div will be replicated as well as table in that div

Comment: can you put back in track by $index -  ng-repeat= "pData in parentData track by $index" and then update pagination-id="{{'policyHolderAppraisals' + $index}}"